# Probabilities of flight route combinations

Tags: probability

An airline is given permission to fly $4$ new routes of its choice. The airline is
considering $12$ new routes: $4$ routes in Florida, $5$ routes in California, and $3$ routes
in Texas. If the airline selects the $4$ new routes at random from the $12$
possibilities, determine the probability that:

a) $2$ are in Florida and $2$ are in Texas

b) $3$ are in California and $1$ is in Florida

c) $1$ is in Florida, $1$ is in California, and $2$ are in Texas

d) at least one is in Texas.

Please can someone help me with this question?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 1):

There are $\dbinom{12}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ routes from the $12$. Under our assumptions, they are equally likely.

(a) There are $\dbinom{4}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ Florida routes from the $4$ available. For **each** of these ways, there are $\dbinom{3}{2}$ ways to choose $2$ Texas routes, for a total of $\dbinom{4}{2}\dbinom{3}{2}$. Divide by $\dbinom{12}{4}$ for the probability.

Parts (b) and (c) are done in a way very similar to (a), so I will leave them to you.

For (d), it is easier to find first the probability that **none** of the routes are to Texas. There are $\dbinom{9}{4}$ ways to choose $4$ routes that don't include Texas. To obtain the probability we entirely avoid Texas, divide by $\dbinom{12}{4}$. To find the probability that at least $1$ route is to Texas, subtract the number just obtained from $1$.

Answer (score 0):

a.) $(\dbinom{4}{2}+\dbinom{3}{1})/\dbinom{12}{4}$,

b.) $(\dbinom{5}{3}+\dbinom{4}{1})/\dbinom{12}{4}$,

c.) $(\dbinom{4}{1}+\dbinom{5}{1}+\dbinom{3}{2})/\dbinom{12}{4}$,

b.) $1-(\dbinom{9}{4}/\dbinom{12}{4}$.

EDIT: added the TeX tags.